# How does the C++ compiler evaluate recursive constexpr functions so quickly?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, constexpr

I've been learning about C++ `constexpr` functions, and I implemented a `constexpr` recursive function to find the nth fibonacci number.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

constexpr long long fibonacci(int num) {
    if (num <= 2) return 1;
    return fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
}

int main() {
    auto start = clock();
    long long num = fibonacci(70);
    auto duration = (clock() - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000.);
    std::cout << num << "\n" << duration << std::endl;
}
```

If I remove the `constexpr` identifier from the `fibonacci()` function, then `fibonacci(70)` takes a *very long* time to evaluate (more than 5 minutes). When I keep it as-is, however, the program still compiles within 3 seconds and prints out the correct result in less than `0.1` milliseconds.

I've learned that `constexpr` functions are evaluated **at compile time**, so this would mean that `fibonacci(70)` is calculated by the compiler in less than 3 seconds! However, it doesn't seem quite right that the C++ compiler would have such better calculation performance than C++ code.

My question is, does the C++ compiler actually evaluate the function between the time I press the "Build" button and the time the compilation finishes? Or am I misunderstanding the keyword `constexpr`?

EDIT: This program was compiled with `g++ 7.5.0` with `--std=c++17`.

Comment: Which compiler? godbolt timed out on your code with GCC 10.2 and clang 11.0 when compiled with `-std=c++17` (with or without `-O3`). Both compilers decided the `constexpr` was too deeply recursive, compiled it to compute at runtime, then timed out at runtime.

Comment: Brute force Fibonacci is slow as hell. the compiler found a better way.

Comment: At a guess - recognising an equivalent iterative form of the recursion, combined with memoisation.   But, ultimately, it will depend on quality of compiler implementation.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Wrong. Op's right - no timeout with `constexpr`

Comment: @bloody: Sigh... "Wrong" implies there is one right answer. [I have two examples where it didn't do compile time optimization](https://godbolt.org/z/45a7qq); that doesn't exclude the possibility that other compilers, flags, etc. might work, but the OP needs to be clear. If I made `long long num = fibonacci(70);` become `constexpr long long num = fibonacci(70);` to force compile-time evaluation, they both died complaining about excessive recursion. That's why I asked how the OP compiled their code; I don't think they're wrong, but it's needed to reproduce their result.

Comment: @bloody: And I just checked. `g++` 7.5 on godbolt does exactly what the OP said, `g++` 10.2 does not. Apparently it's an optimization that was lost in the more recent compiler (or possibly it's a configurable limit on `constexpr` recursion which defaults to a lower value in the newer compiler), which is useful to know.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Indeed with gcc 10.2 it timeouts with constexpr (although not with 9.2). You were right, sorry for an impulsive epithet.

Comment: (off-topic nitpick: If you cared about performance, you wouldn't be using `std::endl` to force pointless flushing of cout between lines, even when the output is a pipe.)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`constexpr` functions have no side-effects and can thus be memoized without worry. Given the disparity in runtime the simplest explanation is that the compiler memoizes constexpr functions during compile-time. This means that `fibonacci(n)` is only computed once for each `n`, and all other recursive calls get returned from a lookup table.

Comment: So essentially, the compiler stores the intermediate values of `fibonacci()` and basically uses dynamic programming instead of recursion? That'd definitely explain why the compiler is so much faster than the program itself, but I've never seen this behavior mentioned before. Is this mentioned someplace in the standard?

Comment: @ahskdjfk Correct. It's an optimization that `constexpr` allows simply due to its nature. I don't believe compilers are *required* to do this optimization however, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: It's probably a play on [the as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). The compiler can do whatever the hell it wants to your code if it thinks it'll be faster and not change the observable behaviour. No reason the compiler can't do it internally when computing the result of a `constxepr` function. The interesting question is if it can see this optimization at compile time for the `constexpr` function, why doesn't it apply the same to the runtime version?

Comment: @orlp: As I mention in the comments above, different versions of gcc definitely *don't* apply this optimization (the OP's 7.5 does, the most recent 10.2 release does not, at least not by default), so yeah, definitely a mileage varying case.

Comment: `constexpr` functions having no side-effects is news to me. Could you point to somewhere in the standard that requires this? It seems like it is implied in [expr.const:5.16](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.16): "An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E [...] would evaluate [...] a modification of an object [...] unless it is applied to a non-volatile lvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of E." IIUC, this rules out modifying objects not local to the constant expression, i.e. side effects

Comment: @user4581301 - Many possible explanations for why the compiler would "see" the optimisation at compile time for a `constexpr` function and not for the "runtime version". `constexpr` allows the compiler to *assume* things but must do analysis to conclude those things for the "runtime" version. That analysis may not be done (it can be expensive), so the optimisation is not done. Conversely, a compiler might gallop ahead attempting to evaluate a `constexpr` function until it exhausts memory.  Compiler quality of implementation depends on many things.

Comment: I wouldn't be happy with my compiler introducing an invisible, uncontrollable, hash table to memoize my functions at runtime. Memory at compile time is "cheap", though, so that transformation seems reasonable while evaluating constexpr.

Comment: @AlexReinking I'm telling you nothing new here considering your profile -- compilers introduce a lot of "invisible, uncontrollable" data in your program, don't they? I'd prefer a hash table over an uncontrollable stack any time ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Compile-time evaluation has the advantage of being able to *make sure* it is actually a constant and thus memoizable, and otherwise just delegate to non-memoized runtime-code.

Comment: @Deduplicator Since the compiler is so sure at compile time it could nicely compile that in ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Proving that for all inputs (or determine those for which it is true) is a whole different ballgame to demonstrating that for specific values. Not to say there aren't many cases that is feasible.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes yes, but I was only talking of this program here, with this specific, compile-time constant argument. *You* said the compiler is "able to make sure it [the result] is actually a constant"! Now don't try to wiggle out. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

To add some details to what other's pointed out: `constexpr` function doesn't have to be computed at runtime and one of the parameters that can affect it is `-fconstexpr-ops-limit`.

On GCC 10.2.0, `-fconstexpr-ops-limit=1000000000` (1B) and `fibonacci(40)` results in a pre-compiled value, but if you drop the limit to 10000000 (10M) then function is computed at run-time. If you want to make sure the value is always computed at compile time, you need to mark `long long num` as `constexpr` in addition to the `fibonacci` function.

Note: the opposite example would be a non-constexpr function computed at compile time (optimized out) and marking it with `__attribute__ ((const))` might help compiler make such decision. However, my compiler didn't optimize it out.

Comment: Note: If you use `constexpr long long num`, that guarantees it won't be computed at run-time. It doesn't guarantee it will be computed at compile-time; it just ensures that when the compiler might otherwise fall back to run-time evaluation, the compilation fails instead.

Answer (score 1):

In g++ 8.3.0, if you use `constexpr` in this case, it computes the value you are using and outputs the result as a constant. This is even without optimizations:

```
//#include <iostream>

constexpr long long fibonacci(int num){
    if(num <= 2){return 1;}
    return fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    //double start = clock();
    long long num = fibonacci(70);
    //std::cout << num << std::endl;
    //cout << (clock()-start)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
        .file   "constexpr.cc"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
        movabsq $190392490709135, %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I was wondering why there is so huge difference between the code and the compiler in terms of execution time.

It seems it computes it without recursion. With recursion is just too slow.

What surprises me is that it can convert a recursive function into a iterative one, even without optimization, at compile time. At least that's what it seems.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments above `constexpr` function call as in the question:

```
long long num = fibonacci(70);
```

is performed in run-time. On-line compilers simply kill the running program due to timeout: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G8MvYTf9h

If you want to evaluate the function during compilation, then either add one more `constexpr`:

```
constexpr long long num = fibonacci(70);
```

or in C++20 define the function as immediate with `consteval`:

```
consteval long long fibonacci(int num)
```

In either case you will get a compilation error in any modern compiler due to "evaluation exceeding step limit" or similar, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9919G4sTh

A good alternative to easy and very fast compute Fibonacci recursive function in compile-time is via template `constexpr` constants:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N> constexpr size_t fib = fib<N-1> + fib<N-2>;
template<> constexpr size_t fib<1> = 1;
template<> constexpr size_t fib<2> = 1;

int main() { std::cout << fib<70>; }
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ce35vYPa7